# Magento cart price rules conditions not working properly

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

I have a discount of free shipping which I want to apply when the shipping address is in the U.S. and the subtotal is $100 or over.

I am trying to exclude Hawaii and Alaska from receiving the free shipping but even after excluding it, its still giving the free shipping to Alaska and Hawaii.

[image]

Can someone help? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Recreated your rule and in my installation, it works:

Can you please retry following this guide:

1. Create a new rule under Marketing -> Cart Price Rule (as you probably already did)
2. Set the rule like the following images

[image: shipping-rule]

[image: more-rule]

3. Now save and clear your cookies. Add a product to your bag and start simulating as the following screenshots. This problem is not reported in any Magento version but if the issue persists can you tell me what is your Magento version exactly?

[image: usa]

[image: hawaii]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other answers, also verify that your sales cart rule indexer is set to "update on save" - M2 2.3.5

```
magento indexer:show-mode salesrule_rule
Sales Rule:                                        Update on Save
```

If it is on "update on schedule", it will not work/apply on the cart page since that rule record not correctly added in `magento_salesrule_filter` table. It will be fixed after the default schedule reindex of the `salesrule_rule`. Otherwise, you may have to manually reindex the `salesrule_rule`.

```
magento indexer:reindex salesrule_rule
```

This scenario only occurred to newly created sales cart rules without using the coupon.

```
Dev note:

Line 171: ->setValidationFilter() - magento/codepool/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Validator.php
Line 51: aroundSetValidationFilter() - magento/codepool/vendor/magento/module-advanced-sales-rule/Model/ResourceModel/Plugin/Rule/Collection.php
```

Hope this will help someone & happy code debugging!

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your conditions displayed in following screenshot:

[image]

I hope it may helpful to anyone.